# Random win32 exit code

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to learn win32 API by following some tutorial.
(Though, I did very minor tweaking to create a borderless fixed window.)

However, my simplest window application is exiting with some random code.
I have no idea why it is not exiting with code '0'.

For extra information, I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Pro.
Source code's file extension is .c and the compiler setting is probably default.
I created the project as an empty win32 application (not console).

Please, some help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                      HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                      LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                      INT nCmdShow) {
    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    MSG msg;

    ZeroMemory(&wcex, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc  = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass1";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(
            NULL,
            L"Failed to register window!",
            L"ERROR",
            MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        L"WindowClass1",
        L"Application",
        WS_POPUP,
        0, 0,
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN),
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN),
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);


    if (hWnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(
            NULL,
            L"Failed to create window!",
            L"ERROR",
            MB_OK |  MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Msg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are reading the exit code?

Comment: After I close the window with alt+f4, the output window in Visual Studio tells me which exit code my application terminated with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your program, `GetMessage` is in fact returning `-1` which is an error condition. Your message loop terminates when `GetMessage` returns a value <=0, and so it terminates when `GetMessage` returns -1.

Now, because the final call to `GetMessage` fails with an error, the value of `msg.wParam` is not well-defined. You should not return it as an exit code. You should only return `msg.wParam` as an exit code when the final call to `GetMessage` returned 0. This is all made clear in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx).

You can see all this if you change your message loop to look like this:

```
while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, hWnd, 0, 0 )) != 0)
{ 
    if (bRet == -1)
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }
    else
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }
}

return msg.wParam;
```

On my machine, the `bRet == -1` route is selected and the error code is 1400. Which is [`ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385.aspx). I'm not quite sure why your app is behaving in this way, but I'm content that I've answered the question you asked about exit codes!

Comment: This is extremely late, but isn't GetMessage suppose to be 
GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)? I've had it cause problems if I used a HWND with it.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond covering the entire screen with a blank window, necessitating the use of ALT-F4 to exit your app, things look good, except for one thing:

GetMessage, despite claiming to return 'BOOL' actually returns int: some positive value when successful, 0 when WM_QUIT is received and -1 in the case of an error. Microsoft's policy of returning "*BOOL plus a lil' something something*" from GetMessage (and other functions) is stupid and dangerous for this reason, and they should be flogged for it.

If GetMessage returns -1 then the contents of msg may or may not be valid; in other words wParam may be zero or it may be `potato`. This could translate into the "random" exit codes you are seeing.

I suggest something like this:

```
int nRet;

do
{
    nRet = GetMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0);

    if(nRet == -1)
        return GetLastError();

    if(nRet != 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
} while(nRet != 0);

return msg.wParam;
```

Comment: Thank you! But I believe David answered it first.

Comment: You're welcome. First or second doesn't matter - what's important is that you got the answer you needed.

Comment: Nik is right. You should accept the best answer rather than the fastest. In this case they appear to be pretty much identical!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I didn't mean it like that actually (although I do think one should accept the best answer). I meant that I don't mind about getting the "Accept" or being "first" to post. I'm satisfied if someone gets the answer they need - from me or someone else. And yes, funny how our answers are almost identical.

Comment: I didn't take it in a bad way. I do so often see sloppy quick answers being accepted ahead of much more worthy answers that by necessity took longer to write. That's all I meant.